# Arithmetic expression evaluation oz mozart

Tags: arithmetic-expressions, oz, mozart

I have a problem and I don't really know how to implement it in OZ:
Suppose that you are given an arithmetic expression described by a tree constructed from tuples as follows:

1. An integer is described by a tuple int(N), where N is an integer.
2. An addition is described by a tuple add(X Y), where both X and Y are arithmetic expressions.
3. A multiplication is described by a tuple mul(X Y), where both X and Y are arithmetic expressions.

Implement a function Eval that takes an arithmetic expression and returns its value.

For example, `add(int(1) mul(int(3) int(4)))` is an arithmetic expression and its evaluation returns **13**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a bit sad that you didn't show your attempts so far.

Anyway. Typically, when dealing with such problems, you think in terms of recursion. And [pattern matching](http://mozart.github.io/mozart-v1/doc-1.4.0/tutorial/node5.html#control.pattern) is a good way to analyze the expression.

For instance, if you capable to evaluate `int(4)` then it is pretty evident how to evaluate `add(int(4) int(4))` with a simple recursion:

```
declare
proc {Eval Exp Res}
   case Exp
   of int(N) then Res = N
   [] add(X Y) then
      local R1 R2 in
         {Eval X R1}
         {Eval Y R2}
         Res = R1 + R2
      end
   end
end
```

Now you can expand it with `mul` or any other expression.